# Date differences in days from a file

Tags: shell, date, date-difference

I extracted 2 date columns from a text file and I want to create a new file with the date difference (number of days) for each row. Manually inputing the dates to the command line using `datediff` (from https://github.com/hroptatyr/dateutils) works (e.g. `ddiff 2014-03-17   2013-09-19` returns `-179`). There are many rows and is not feasible to do it manually.

Piping the file content `cat dates_file.txt | ddiff` and also through xargs `cat dates_file.txt | xargs | ddiff` gets me `ddiff: Error: reference DATE must be specified`. What would be a good approach?

**dates_file.txt**

`2014-02-03  2013-11-29
2015-12-07  2015-05-13
2015-01-23  2014-07-31
2012-02-28  2012-01-17
2014-03-17  2013-09-19
...`

**expected output**

`-66
-208
-176
-42
-179
...`

Comment: Please provided a sample your `dates_file.txt` and your expected output after parsing that file

Comment: Hi @oliv, I now added samples in the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `ddiff` with `xargs`:

```
xargs -n 2 ddiff < dates_file.txt
```

Alternatively, with `perl` and the `Date::Calc` module:

```
perl -MDate::Calc -ne '@a = /^(\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d)\s+(\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d)$/ or die; print Date::Calc::Delta_Days(@a), "\n"'
```

Provide either the file in argument after the command, or the data to the standard input.

This does error checking with `or die` in case some lines do not have the expected format. Adapt the regexp or the script if the file format may be different...